# via email on receiver

Tags: email, massemailmessage

Is there a way to skip this via field when someone gets email from salesforce?
I don't want my clients to see this when we are sending them emails.

Please advise,
Darko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Google Apps for email, here is a [step-by-step guide for sending Salesforce email via your Google Apps domain](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gAC3KvBAgTok-DMVt6HUdavhrLSKibXIj3IC_0iQRMo/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are referring to the "Via" link in Gmail when receiving emails from Salesforce.  This is a Gmail feature and you can read about it here:

[Why am I seeing extra information next to the sender’s name?](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182?hl=en)

To resolve it you will need to implement some changes on  your SPF record and add the Salesforce domain to them.

More information on the articles below

[Sender Policy Framework (SPF) - Salesforce SPF Record](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000006347&language=en_US)

[Removing Via link by Gmail](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000175959&language=en_US)

Comment: @DarkoTodorovski If you found this helpful, please considering accepting this answer as it may benefit other people in the future.

Comment: done it was quite helpful